# Swift. Почему не выполняется условие сравнения в операторе if

Tags: swift

Потихоньку начинаю программировать на Swift и наткнулся на проблему, помогите решить.
Есть переменная в AppDelegate, которая получает значение через GCDAsyncSocket с сервера. Розетку прописал тоже в AppDelegate.

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
        
        tcpClientSocket = GCDAsyncSocket(delegate: self, delegateQueue: DispatchQueue.main)
return true
    }

func socket(_ sock: GCDAsyncSocket, didRead data: Data, withTag tag: Int) {
        dataRx = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8)!
        print(dataRx)
        NotificationCenter.default.post(name: NSNotification.Name(rawValue: "ReceivedData"), object: nil)
        tcpClientSocket?.readData(withTimeout: -1, tag: 0)
    }
```

Далее запускаю метод в subview через Notification и передаю туда переменную через UIAplication.shared.

```
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(isConnected), name: NSNotification.Name(rawValue: "ReceivedData"), object: nil)

@objc func isConnected() {
        let statusLbl = appDelegate.dataRx
        print("Status Label Before: \(statusLbl)")
        if statusLbl == "ok" { // далее код не выполняется
            statusLabel.text = statusLbl
            print("Status Label After: \(statusLbl)")
        }
        else { print("Error") }
```

Результаты с консоли:

> Status Label Before: ok
>
> Error
>
> Status Label Before: ok
>
> Error

Получается что условие в операторе не выполняется и переходит в else. Но при этом сама переменная передается.

Comment: Как вариант, у вас опечатка в "ok", "о" русская, а приходит английская "o", поэтому это другой "ok".

Comment: Хотелось бы мне что бы все было так просто, но нет) я перепроверил и там и там напечатано на англ, «ок» одинаковые.

Comment: Что будет, если так ``if statusLbl.hasPrefix("ok")``?

Comment: А вот это сработало)) спасибо!

Comment: Единственное для меня так и остаётся загадкой почему условие statusLbl==“ok” не выполняется. Буду признателен если объясните.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

скорее всего в ответе содержатся пробелы, как вариант заменить их и уже после выполнять проверку:

```
statusLbl.replacingOccurrences(of: " ", with: "")
        if statusLbl == "ok" { 
            statusLabel.text = statusLbl
            print("Status Label After: \(statusLbl)")
        }
```

Comment: Да, так и есть. Метод помог с этим справиться. Спасибо.

Answer (score 0):

Если `if statusLbl == "ok"` не работает, а `if statusLbl.hasPrefix("ok")`, при после `ok` находится что-то еще, невидимое при печати. Например, символ конца строки или любой другой служебный символ. Поскольку значения приходит с сервера, то это неудивительно и даже ожидаемо.

Comment: Да, действительно ответ с сервера содержал символ. Метод replacingOccerrences с предыдущего ответа помог с этим справиться. Спасибо за объяснение.